# Remove extra string characters in decimal formatting

Tags: r, regex

how do I remove just the ".00" in a data frame column: so that `5.00% /GP per tonne` becomes `5% / GP per tonne` ? I am trying something like the below but it is saying invalid regexp.

```
sched$duty_rate <- c("5.00% /GP per tonne","10.00% /GP per tonne")

for(i in 1:nrow(sched)){
  sched$duty_rate[i] <- gsub("[.]?[0-9]*(?=%)","\\%",sched$duty_rate[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
sched$duty_rate <- gsub("\\.0+(%)", "\\1", sched$duty_rate)
```

**Details**:

- `\.` - a literal dot
- `0+` - one or more `0` chars
- `(%)` - Group 1: a `%` char (so that we do not remove zeros from other contexts, only between `.` and `%`)

See [the R demo](https://ideone.com/PEXM8W):

```r
duty_rate <- c("5.00% /GP per tonne","10.00% /GP per tonne", "5.0% /GP per 2.000 tonne","10.0000% /GP per 20.000 tonne")
gsub("\\.0+(%)", "\\1", duty_rate)
## => [1] "5% /GP per tonne"         "10% /GP per tonne"       
##    [3] "5% /GP per 2.000 tonne"   "10% /GP per 20.000 tonne"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dhWQAz/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub`, i.e.

```
sub('.00', '', sched$duty_rate, fixed = TRUE)
[1] "5% /GP per tonne"  "10% /GP per tonne"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, fairly simple and readable implementation can be derived with use of [`str_remove`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_remove.html) function offered via the [`stringr`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/index.html) package.

```r
x <- c("5.00% /GP per tonne", "10.00% /GP per tonne")
stringr::str_remove(string = x, pattern = ".00")
#> [1] "5% /GP per tonne"  "10% /GP per tonne"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `[.]?[0-9]*(?=%)` matches an optional dot, optional digits and asserts `%` to the right which matches more than a mandatory dot and only zeroes.

You can make the positive lookahead work using `perl=TRUE` and match a dot and one or more zeroes using a more specific pattern `[.]0+(?=%)`

```
duty_rate <- c("5.00% /GP per tonne","10.00% /GP per tonne", "5.0% /GP per 2.000 tonne","10.0000% /GP per 20.000 tonne")
gsub("[.]0+(?=%)", "", duty_rate, perl=TRUE)
```

Output

```
[1] "5% /GP per tonne"         "10% /GP per tonne"       
[3] "5% /GP per 2.000 tonne"   "10% /GP per 20.000 tonne"
```

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/dvr0q1).